# Google Maps and List in one Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, maps

I am trying to fit a Google Maps View and a ListView into one activty.
The MapsView shall take 2/3 of the left screen, and the list 1/3 of the right side (in Landscape).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA3XN.png

Both, the MapsView and the ListView, will receive the same JSON information, they will get onCreate().
I was already able to fit the MapsView on 2/3 of the screen, but the ListView wont receive any data.
Can someone tell me, how to adress a ListView correct, when the superclass isnt ListActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create and set a list adaptor for the list view. So rather than just calling setAdaptor() within a list activity you'd get an instance of the List view from your layout

```
ListView l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
```

and set the adaptor of that.

```
l.setAdaptor(adaptor);
```